# Change iOS app name "While In Review"

Tags: app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Can the name of the app, as it is in iTunes Connect, be changed while the app is in "While In Review" state?

Comment: Recently it can't, since there were "developers" who abused this feature to create fake Cydia tweaks (which were just BS).

Comment: Oh sucks, but makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done... You would have to resubmit it in a small update.